# One Line Command in Linux Bash

Tags: linux, bash, command, exe

I am trying to write a basic one line Linux Bash command,
which gives all the numbers between 1 - 1000 as an input to an exe program.

the exe program looks like this:

```
please insert 1:   1(wanted input)
please insert 2:   2(wanted input)
.
.
.
.
please insert 1000:  1000(wanted input)
success!
```

so I have tried writing this linux bash command:

```
for((i=1;i<=1000;i+=1)); do echo "$i"|./the_exe_file; done
```

but the problem is that my command OPENS the exe file on each iterate of the for... which means, only the first input (1) is right.
And, for some reason, the input that is given to the exe file seems not to be good. 
what can I do? Where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked the exe to be opened in every loop iteration. It you only need it to be opened a single time, take it out of the loop:

```
for((i=1;i<=1000;i+=1)); do echo "$i"; done | ./the_exe_file
```

Comment: If it worked and solved your problem, it would be good that you mark the answer as accepted :-)

Answer (score 1):

Likewise, you might find it more readable to use the tool designed for this.

```
seq 1 1000 | ./the_exe_file
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `seq` may not be installed on the current machine, while `bash` is guaranteed to be available on a machine running a `bash` script.

Comment: True. If it's there, I'd use it. If not, I'd use a loop rather than bothering to install it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
printf '%s\n' {1..1000} | ./the_exe_file
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
$ for f in {1..1000}; do echo $f; done
```

to test:

```
$ for f in {1..1000}; do echo $f; done  | uniq | wc -l
1000
```